# Modular Arithmathics

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

SO basically I am learning number theory chapter in the Discrete Maths.
Now I really don't understand a proof here.
[image: Picture]
SO basically it is a corollary which says

```
Let m be a positive integer and let a and b be integers. Then
(a + b) mod m = ((a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m
and
ab mod m = ((a mod m)(b mod m)) mod m.
```

Now the proof goes something like this.

```
Proof: By the definitions of mod m and of congruence modulo m, we know that a ≡
(a mod m) (mod m) and b ≡ (b mod m) (mod m). Hence, Theorem 5 tells us that
a + b ≡ (a mod m) + (b mod m) (mod m)
and
ab ≡ (a mod m)(b mod m) (mod m).
```

What i really can't get here is how is the

```
a ≡ (a mod m) (mod m) and b ≡ (b mod m) (mod m)
```

I know about the reflexive property about mod but how come this two mod. what i know is
a ≡ (a mod m) but how they are saying a ≡ (a mod m) (mod m)

Comment: There are dozens too many "mod m" appearing in that... I hate the way it is written.

Comment: The superior way of writing and thinking about this in my opinion from a mathematical standpoint is not that mod m is an operator, but rather a context.  The context only needs to be written once to the side or mentioned ahead of time.  You have by definition $a \equiv A\pmod{m}$ if and only if $(a-A)$ is a multiple of $m$.  The theorems they are trying to share with you here rewritten are that if $a\equiv A\pmod{m}$ and $b\equiv B\pmod{m}$ then $a+b\equiv A+B\pmod{m}$ as well as $a\times b\equiv A\times B\pmod{m}$

Comment: The proof?  Well, in the case of addition $(a+b)-(A+B)=(a-A)+(b-B)$ is a multiple of $m$ plus another multiple of $m$ and therefore a multiple of $m$, proving the claim by definition.  For multiplication, $(a\times b)-(A\times B)=(a\times b)-(a\times B) + (a\times B)-(A\times B) = a\times (b-B) + B\times (a-A)$, which is the sum of multiples of multiples of $m$, and thus also a multiple of $m$.

Comment: Your expression "$a\equiv (a \operatorname{\mathbf{mod}} m)$" is not well-formed. Maybe you mean "$a\equiv a \pmod m$"? The text uses the two notations "$a\operatorname{\mathbf{mod}}m$" for the unique integer $r\in\{0,\dots,m-1\}$ such that $a=qm+r$ for some $q\in\mathbb Z$ and the notation "$a\equiv b\pmod{m}$" for the congruence relation given by $m \mid (a-b)$.